# Decomposition procedure of closed subspaces in Hilbert Space $\mathcal H$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\mathcal H$ be a Hilbert Space.

I then have a theorem saying:

Let $U$ be a closed subspace of $\mathcal H$. Then we can write $\mathcal H = U \oplus U^{\bot}$.

Now why is the following procedure possible ?

Choose some unit vector $v_1 \in \mathcal H$ and then write $\text {span}(v_1) \oplus \text {span}(v_1)^{\bot} (1)$ (**This can be done, since** $\text {span}(v_1)$ **is a closed subspace** (1). If $\text {span}(v_1)^{\bot} \neq \{0\}$, then choose a unit vector $v_2 \in \text {span}(v_1)^{\bot}$ and write $\text {span}(v_1) \oplus  \text {span}(v_1)^{\bot} \oplus \text {span}(v_1,v_2)^{\bot} (2)$. This can be continued as long as the orthogonal complement isn't the zero subspace.

Can someone explain how we can go from $(1)$ to $(2)$ provided $v_2$ exist ? I mean $\text {span}(v_1)^{\bot}$ is not a closed subspace of $\mathcal H$ or is it ? But it is not equal to $\mathcal H$, which is required in the theorem ? Can the general step be explained ?

Comment: The procedure only works if $U$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Functional_Analysis/Hilbert_spaces.

Comment: Can you explain how to go from $(1)$ to $(2)$ ?

Comment: If $V$ is a subspace, what is by definition $V{^\bot}$?

Comment: A subspace. But is it closed ? And if I use my theorem on it I get something that involve $v_1$, which is already in the sum ?

Comment: I'm asking what concrete set is.

Answer (score 2):

There's an error in what you wrote for (2). It should have been
$$
         \mathcal{H} = \mbox{span}(v_1)\oplus\left[\mbox{span}(v_2)\oplus\mbox{span}(v_1,v_2)^{\perp}\right] \\
             = \mbox{span}(v_1)\oplus\mbox{span}(v_2)\oplus\mbox{span}(v_1,v_2)^{\perp}.
$$
For any subset $S$ of $\mathcal{H}$, the set $S^{\perp} = \{ x : (x,s)=0,\; \forall s \in S \}$ is a subspace and it is closed because the inner-product is continuous with respect to the norm topology: $|(x,y)| \le \|x\|\|y\|$.

Comment: But is $S^{\bot}$ also a Hilbert Space ? And why is it $\text {span}(v_1,v_2)^{\bot}$ ?

Comment: @user111854 : Yes, because $S^{\perp}$ is a closed subspace of a Hilbert space.

Comment: And how do you rewrite what comes from the decomposition of $S^{\bot}$ to $\text {span}(v_1,v_2)^{\bot}$ ?

Comment: The orthogonal complement of $\mbox{span}(v_2)$ inside $\mbox{span}(v_{1})^{\perp}$ consists of all $x \in \mbox{span}(v_{1})^{\perp}$ which are orthogonal to $v_{2}$, which gives you $\mbox{span}(v_1,v_2)^{\perp}$.

Comment: Aha ! I know a subspace $S$ is closed if every sequence $x_n$ in $S$ converges to $x \in S$ or if the complement is open. Why does the continuity of the inner product imply that the closedness of $S^{\bot}$ ?

Comment: @user111854 If you have a continuous function $f$ from $\mathcal{H}$ to $\mathbb{C}$  then what do you know about $f^{-1}\{0\}$?

Comment: Sorry, I can't say.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand the procedure you are describing, but for any subset $U$ of an inner product space we have an easy description of $U^{\bot}$. $$U^{\bot}=\cap_{x\in U}\operatorname {Ker}E_x$$
where $E_x \in \mathcal H'$ (the continuous dual) is defined by $E_x(y)=\langle y, x \rangle$. So $U^{\bot}$ is an intersection of closed subspaces hence is a closed subspace.

Showing $U\oplus U^{\bot}=\mathcal H$ as vector spaces is pretty straightforward. Choose an orthonormal basis for $U$. For any $x\in \mathcal H$, take the obvious projection onto $U$ and show that the difference is in $U^{\bot}$.

Comment: I need to understand how to go from $(1)$ to $(2)$.